# How to Import Fonts Properly

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;"">Test</h1>
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Test</h1></h2>
</body>        
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
</style>
```

I'm trying to import this font, however for both  and , the font doesn't show up. How do I fix this?

Comment: You put your CSS directly in the HTML or you are maintaining it as a separate file ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra quotation mark in your code.

Replace

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;"">Test</h1>
```

With

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">Test</h1>
```

I would, however, not write inline CSS to style my fonts because of readability and ease of maintenance.

Try this instead,

In your HTML file, do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 style="header-style-1">Test</h1>
    <h1 style="header-style-2">Test</h1></h2>
</body>        
</html>
```

In a separate CSS file (in this case, style.css), do this.

```
.header-style-1 {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

.header-style-2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First You Should remove '"'

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;"">Test</h1>
```

change this

```
<h1 style="font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;">Test</h1>
```

next you can help this-->https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-import-google-fonts-in-css-file.html#:~:text=Open%20Google%20Fonts%20and%20follow,(in%20HTML%20or%20CSS).

Answer (score 0):

In the head of your html file, write this line

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for fix error

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```